# How Google analytics count the time the user stays on a web page

Tags: google-analytics

Does google analytics count the time the user stays on a web page when the browser is minimised or the user has switched to another tab and website or for some reason the webpage is not on focus?

Comment: This doesn't seem to qualify as a programming question.

Comment: Short answer, Yes, but please remember to post non-coding questions to Webmasters.

Comment: Nobody answers them on other sites so when i get answer here they can move the questions to other site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing to keep in mind is that Google Analytics isn't "counting" the time a user is on a page. There's no timer going, so it doesn't matter if the page is in an active tab or in the background.

The TL;DR of how GA calculates time is by figuring it out on the back end after all the hits have come in. To put that another way, if you were on `index.html` and then 5 minutes later you visited `about.html` without visiting any other page on the site, GA assumes you were on `index.html` for 5 minutes.

Of course, it's more complicated than that, and here are two great articles that go in depth on the details.

- http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/02/29/understanding-google-analytics-time-calculations/
- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1006924?hl=en